# Why am I getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error when trying to run HTML/CSS files with 'run without debugging'?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, localhost, configuration-files

I'm not really a programmer, I'm just learning some basic stuff. So I was working on some html/css and I tried to "run without debugging" and it gave me a blank page, telling me "This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

This happens now for any file I try to run through the option "run without debugging" or "start debugging." It doesn't happen when I right click and select "open in browser." It happens for every file. I have tried clearing cache and disabling antivirus programs, but no change so far. Any ideas why this is happening?

I have tried clearing cache and disabling antivirus programs